# Getting SCNNode positions and rotations

Tags: swift, scenekit

Im using a tap gesture hit results to return a SCNNode and now I want to get its positions and rotations but my code does seem to produce the results I want. For some reason I keep getting the same values back regardless of the position or rotation of the node. When the node moves again and I tap it onscreen again Im get the same values for both.

```
func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let location: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: scnView)
    let hits = self.scnView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
    if let tappedNode = hits.first?.node {
        let nodePosition = tappedNode.worldPosition
        let nodeOrientation = tappedNode.worldOrientation
        print("\(nodePosition) and \(nodeOrientation)")
    }
}
```

Ive tried `.position`, `.simdPosition`, `.transform` but nothing changes.
The node is added to the scene root node.

Comment: How are you moving the node? Are you using physics? Then take a look at the `presentation` property. Are you sure you get the correct node and not a parent or child?

Comment: Okay Ill check the presentation property. Yes the node its being selected because I can print the selected node to the console.

Comment: That works thankyou. Im not sure why the other attribute are there on the node itself if the values dont represent much to the user.